# how to replace string/ word in parsing html with php?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing, html-parsing

i have table like

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="data" class="outer">
        <tr><td>Date</td><td>12-09-12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Price</td><td>15.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Count</td><td>67</td></tr>          
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

i have to parse this to give out put for more than 100 
but i am unable to get how value for  "Date" "12-09-12" can be replaced with new value from database value.

please give me a small example

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($page);

$items = $html->find('Date');
```

`

```
$s = '<html>
  <body>
    <table id="data" class="outer">
        <tr><td>Date</td><td>12-09-12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Price</td><td>15.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Count</td><td>67</td></tr>          
 </table>
  </body>
</html>';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($s);

$oElement = $document->getElementById('data');
$tds = $oElement->getElementsByTagName('td');
if( 'td' == strtolower($tds->item(0)->tagName) AND 'date' == strtolower($tds->item(0)->nodeValue) )

{
    echo 'Old value: ' . $tds->item(1)->nodeValue;
    echo '<hr/>';

    $tds->item(1)->nodeValue = '13-08-11';
    echo $document->saveHTML(); //output modified HTML
}
?>
```

`can anyone help me ?

Comment: You have control auf the table? Why you try to parse the output ??? Move to the code where you create the page and modify your stuff there.

Comment: as this html is a content of a email. i need to parse html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) package it can be done like this.

```
$s = '<html>
  <body>
    <table id="data" class="outer">
        <tr><td>Date</td><td>12-09-12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Price</td><td>15.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Count</td><td>67</td></tr>          
    </table>
  </body>
</html>';

include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = str_get_html($s);
$html->find('table#data tr td', 1)->innertext = '13-08-11';
echo $html;
```

`table#data tr td` selector finds all TD tags inside TR tags inside TABLE with `id="data"`. `$html->find('table#data tr td', 1)` returns second of found elements (index is 1).

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

```php
<?php
$s = '<html>
  <body>
    <table id="data" class="outer">
        <tr><td>Date</td><td>12-09-12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Price</td><td>15.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Count</td><td>67</td></tr>          
    </table>
  </body>
</html>';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($s);

$oElement = $document->getElementById('data');
if($oElement)
{
    $tds = $oElement->firstChild->childNodes;
    if( 'td' == strtolower($tds->item(0)->tagName) AND 'date' == strtolower($tds->item(0)->nodeValue) )
    {
        echo 'Old value: ' . $tds->item(1)->nodeValue;
        echo '<hr/>';

        $tds->item(1)->nodeValue = '13-08-11';
        echo $document->saveHTML(); //output modified HTML
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'No elements found with id="data"';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply  its giving error like Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in dashboard/test1.php on line 16

Comment: please, post your code and let me see, I've tested my code and it worked for me. Maybe your HTML is different (does not contain a node with id="data") ?

Comment: i just copied your code only and tested  its giving error

Comment: code is attached to my question review it please

Comment: just copied, nothing was changed

Comment: which php version you're using? DOMElement::getElementsByTagName is available since PHP5. When you're doing print_r($oElement), what do you get?

Comment: i think it is not working on my server. actually version 5.3.13. Is there is any other solution for me

Comment: check out modified answer. I've removed getElementsByTagName call (but it was working for me, its strange you're getting an error...). New way is faster ;)

Comment: i think dom is not working with my server. Its working with localhost.

Comment: then why `$document = new DOMDocument();` line works? did you tried modified answer? Try to search `dom` in `phpinfo()` output, are you able to find such section?

Comment: yes i got information, that dom is not working with my server.

Comment: ok, check out my another answer using Simple HTML DOM package

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="data" class="outer">
        <tr><td>Date</td><td id="date">12-09-12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Price</td><td>15.00</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Count</td><td>67</td></tr>          
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

in javascript:

```
var date = <?=$_row['date']?>;
$('date').html('date');
```